# Route to images and css in Play Framework 2.10

Tags: image, playframework, routes, assets, playframework-2.1

My designer have finished the whole website and I need to make it work using Play 2.10.

The problem is:

All assets are being loaded this way

```
<img src="images/logo.png" alt="" />
```

I could not route properly.

I tryied this

```
GET  images/*file  controllers.Assets.at(path="/public/images", file)
```

But the result is 
 
**'/' expected but `i' found**

How can I route to my assets without rewriting all the urls?

Thanks in advance
Leonardo Rodrigo

Answer (score 1):

The slash is missing, try:

```
GET  /images/*file  controllers.Assets.at(path="/public/images", file)
```